# Advice for efficient stream sliding window processing

Tags: c++, stream, real-time, time-series

At each time t (every 10ms) I receive a set of ints

```
{i_{0,t}, i_{1,t}, i_{2,t}}_t
```

which goes into separate buffers:

```
seq_0 = [...,i_{0,t-2},i_{0,t-1},i_{0,t},...], seq_1 and seq_2
```

I need to make real-time computations on the sequences for a set of sliding window of different sizes. For example: for a sliding window of size `3`, I will compute function `f()` on samples received at time `t`, `t-1`, `t-2` in each buffered sequences.

```
at time t for seq_0 I compute f([i_{0,t-2},i_{0,t-1},i_{0,t}])
```

I would like some advice for data structure (c++) to use or code design.
In practice I would like 4 different sizes of sliding window.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) with the size equal to the width of the largest window.

Comment: I am wondering if there is any possible optimization if I have to handle a large number of sequences and window sizes. Is there a way to avoid data copy into the different circular buffer ? Thx.

Comment: Answer accepted btw, thx. Waiting for any other idea for optimization.

Comment: @Eric: Come to think of it, you only need one circular buffer. See the updated answer.

Comment: Depending on the choice of the window sizes (max size = N; power of 2 ?), any advice for 'masking' parts of the circular buffer to apply f() on windows of size < N ?

Comment: @Eric: You don't really need to mask it. You can just apply the function to the relevant part of the buffer (make the function take the buffer and a pair of wraparound indices).